# I have to open a web page in port 8080

Tags: html, linux, python-sockets, honeypot

I used socket programming to open port 8080 in my honeypot and linked it to my server IP which I started using "sudo apache2 start" in my linux.
But my socket program has been linked to html page which I expected to open in port 8080 but when I search for IP:8080 in browser it just displays entire html code like text instead of displaying html page.Any solutions??

Comment: hey, be more specific with your question I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Trapmap - Your page could be invalid. You may want to upload it to [The W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload).